# Get timezone offset in GMT from abbreviation

Tags: php

I wanna to get the timezone offset in gmt from their abbrevation using php.I have search about it and did not get any answer.

For example:- I wanna to convert America/Los_Angeles into Gmt -7 using php

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get "-7" part:

```
$dateTimeZone = new DateTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
$dateTimeZ = new DateTime("now", $dateTimeZone);
$timeOffset = $dateTimeZone->getOffset($dateTimeZ)/3600;
```

Comment: it's in seconds so divide it by 3600